# connecting to websocket make webworker un-responsive in Microsoft edge

Tags: javascript, websocket, web-worker

So this is weird, when i try to *connect to websocket* (this is only a Microsoft edge issue) it makes so on every second page refresh `webworker` will not accept messages `onMessage` wont trigger at all:

consider the following:

**main.js**

```
    var worker = new Worker("webworker.js");
    worker.postMessage({ type: 'INIT_SOCKET' });

    worker.addEventListener('message',  (event) => {
        let data = event.data;

        if (typeof data === 'string') {
            data = JSON.parse(data);
        }

        if (data.type === 'SOCKET_INITIALIZED') {
            console.log('inititalized');
        }
    });
```

**webworker.js**

```
    var io = require('socket.io-client');

    var socket;
    onmessage = function(event) {
        var data = event.data;

        console.log('got a event');

        if (typeof data === 'string') {
            data = JSON.parse(data);
        }

        switch (data.type) {
            case 'INIT_SOCKET':
                try {
                    socket = io('xxxx', { transports: [ 'websocket' ], secure: true }); // this line causes the error
                    socket.on('connect', function () {
                        postMessage({
                            type: Consts.SOCKET_INITIALIZED
                        });
                    });
                } catch(e) {
                    console.log('some error ', e);
                }

            break;

        };
    };
```

Comment: What is `this` within `connect` event handler?

Comment: I am not sure where do you see `this`, however if you are generally asking what is the context inside the connection handler, its the handler or window. i am not sure how this is relevant though.

Comment: Is `postMessage` being called with correct context? What is purpose for check of `data`? Is a string passed as message at a portion of `javascript`? Have you tried calling `worker.postMessage({ type: 'INIT_SOCKET' });` after attaching `message` event handler?

Comment: Is `Consts.SOCKET_INITIALIZED` defined?

Answer (score 1):

`require` does not appear to be defined at `Worker` context. Use [`importScripts()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WorkerGlobalScope/importScripts) to import external scripts into `DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope`. For example

```
importScripts("socket.io.js");
```

Could not determine how to stop `io()` call from polling and getting error, probably due to `404` error

> ```
> socket.io.js:7370 WebSocket connection to 
> 'ws://echo.websocket.org/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket' failed:
> Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404
> ```

probably due to being unfamiliar, here, as to how `io()` is implemented. Though was able to define `Socket` object within `Worker` scope.

Approach using `WebSocket` returns expected result

```
const worker = new Worker("webworker.js");

worker.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
  let data = event.data;

  if (typeof data === 'string') {
    console.log(data)
  }

  if (data.type === 'SOCKET_INITIALIZED') {
    console.log('inititalized');
  }
});

worker.postMessage({
  type: 'INIT_SOCKET'
});
```

```
importScripts("socket.io.js");

let sock = io();

console.log(sock); // to demonstrate `Socket` is defined

sock.close(); // closing socket here to prevent `404` polling errors 

self.socket = void 0;

self.onmessage = function(event) {

  var data = event.data;

  console.log('got a event');

  if (typeof data === 'string') {
    data = JSON.parse(data);
  }

  switch (data.type) {
    case 'INIT_SOCKET':
      if (!self.socket) {
        try {

          self.socket = new WebSocket("ws://echo.websocket.org/");

          self.socket.onopen = function(e) {
            socket.send("WebSocket rocks");
            console.log("self.socket event.type:", e.type);
            self.postMessage({
              type: 'SOCKET_INITIALIZED'
            });
          };

          self.socket.onmessage = function(e) {
            console.log(e.data);
            self.socket.close()
          };

          self.socket.onerror = function(e) {
            console.log("self.socket error", e);
          };

          self.socket.onclose = function(e) {
            console.log("self.socket event.type", e.type);
          };

        } catch (e) {
          console.log('some error ', e);
        }

        break;

      };
  }
};
```

plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/zVnLE6qG7Kf4yVSb0aJt?p=preview

Comment: the error i mentioned is very weird because its not consistent, it only appears on every second page refresh, only on edge, and only when the line to connect to socket is included. however i will try your answer more careful. also if require were the issue this error would have happened on every page refresh.

Comment: @NetaMeta Note, have not tried edge. Was not able to reproduce specific issue. Though `WebSocket` appeared to return expected result at chromium. Approach could probably be further adjusted and improved to meet requirement.

Comment: Well if not tested on edge then you have wrong test parameters and your solution is void.  as this occurs Only for edge also, socket.io is not optional.

Comment: @NetaMeta Have not used ie, *indows in some time. Did `javascript` at Answer not return expected result? Should post be deleted?